# Одномерный массив в дерево

Tags: php, treeview

Есть одномерный массив. Порядок возрастания настроен. Как сделать вложенный список ul типа дерева?

[image: скриншот]

То есть самый главный родитель это транспорт потом дочерний элемент легковые автомобили и последний ребенок это mercedes

Comment: это не древовидный вид, у элемента дерева либо должен быть индекс родителя, либо у родителя список детей, иначе вы дерево не сможете сделать. То что у вас, это линейное дерево без потомков

Comment: хрустальный шар предполагает, что массив продолжается?  `[3] => Транспорт`,  `[4] => Грузовые авто`, `[5] => Камаз`, и так далее, по три? И массив длинный, и задача его весь пробежать, и разобрать в дерево, где в корне «Транспорт» будет только один раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно автор хочет нечто подобное:

```
$a = [
  0 => [
    'title' => 'Транспорт',
    'values' => [
      0 => [
        'title' => 'Легковые',
        'values' => [
          0 => ['title' => 'car1'],
          1 => ['title' => 'car2'],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ]
];

function echoUl($tree) {
  echo "<ul>"
  foreach ($tree as $value) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo "<b>" . $value['title'] . "</b><br/>";
    if (isset($value['values'])) {
      echoUl($value['values']);
    }
    echo "</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}

echoUl($a);
```

Предполагаю, что одномерный массив стоит преобразовать в дерево.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = [ 'transport', 'cars', 'mers' ];
foreach( $a as $b ) {
  echo "<ul><li>$b";
}
$i = count($a);
while( $i-- ) {
  echo '</li></ul>';
}
```

Но что-то мне подсказывает, что не это нужно на самом деле.

Comment: и что у вас получится? <ul><li>transport<ul><li>cars<ul><li>mers</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: Совершенно верно. Ровно то, что и заказывали в вопросе. BTW, последнюю фразу в ответе прочитать удалось?

Comment: если верить хрустальному шару, то да, все верно

Comment: разве while( $i-- ) не будет бесконечным циклом?

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис, с чего бы? Впрочем, самостоятельная проверка занимает несколько секунд.

Comment: @Pink Tux, я уже понял что к чему)